# Longitudinal Studies with a Binary "Since Baseline" Variable

Tags: panel-data, binary-data

I came across a study design that I can't seem to find specific literature on:

- Like most longitudinal studies, the subjects are re-measured at different time points
- There is a binary outcome variable, collected at each time point, which asks if the subject did thing ***Y*** "since the study started"
- covariates are being investigated for their ability to predict the event; many of the covariates *are* time-varying.

Let ***Y*** denote the event, Y=1 if event occured, 0 if not.

What this means is, once a subject reports succumbing to event ***Y***, that event is then recorded at all future timepoints for that patient, without distinction from the first time. So if a subject *j* reports ***Y = 1*** at timepoint 1, then ***Y = 1*** enters the dataset at timepoints 1, 2, 3, 4 for subject *j*.

How should this be handled? My gut instinct is that this is not real re-measuring, and that if analyzing by patient+time combination we should only be evaluating if Y happened *since last timepoint* or even discarding observations post-event. But I have struggled to find explicit confirmation of best practices here. The study is dealing with a rare outcome, but I worry we are artificially inflating the frequency of the event by treating each occurrence of ***Y*** in the dataset as an event.